# Create configurable product using multiple bundle products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, bundle-product, recurring

Lot of time, people have inquired about creating bundle product from multiple configurable products. Even extensions are available for the same.

But my requirement is different.
I require to attach payment frequency (recurring profile) attribute to bundle product, and based on that require to generate configurable product.

I am not getting enough pointers for the same.

So basically, what I need is:
When I create configurable product, I should be able to select bundle products, along with simple products.

Any pointers would be helpful.

If ready-made such solution is not available, please suggest what things I should be take care of.

Comment: I am using magento 1.9 CE